# Map enum value to template argument in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, enums

I have an enum class with several members. The goal of the enum is to encode primitive types (e.g. int, long, float, ...) at runtime, so that it's possible to store this information in a database for example. At the same time a lot of classes templated to work on primitive types exist as well.

The problem: I want to create an object from such a templated class, given an enum value that is not a constant. Would this be possible in any way that is cleaner and more scalable than creating a long switch on the enum values (or doing essentially the same with a map as proposed in the answer of [Dynamic mapping of enum value (int) to type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831284/dynamic-mapping-of-enum-value-int-to-type))?

Here's something I've been trying hoping that template type inference could work, but it fails to compile (can be checked here for example: http://rextester.com/VSXR46052):

```
#include <iostream>

enum class Enum {
    Int,
    Long
};

template<Enum T>
struct EnumToPrimitiveType;

template<>
struct EnumToPrimitiveType<Enum::Int> {
    using type = int;
};

template<>
struct EnumToPrimitiveType<Enum::Long> {
    using type = long;
};

template<typename T>
class TemplatedClass
{
public:
    TemplatedClass(T init): init{init} {}
    void printSize() { std::cout << sizeof(init) << std::endl; }
private:
    T init;
};

template<Enum T>
auto makeTemplatedClass(T enumValue) -> TemplatedClass<EnumToPrimitiveType<T>::type>
{
    TemplatedClass<EnumToPrimitiveType<T>::type> ret(5);
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    Enum value{Enum::Int};
    auto tmp = makeTemplatedClass(value);
    tmp.printSize();
}
```

Compile error:

```
source_file.cpp:36:27: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘enumValue’
 auto makeTemplatedClass(T enumValue) -> TemplatedClass<EnumToPrimitiveType<T>::type>
                           ^
source_file.cpp:36:6: warning: variable templates only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
 auto makeTemplatedClass(T enumValue) -> TemplatedClass<EnumToPrimitiveType<T>::type>
      ^
source_file.cpp:36:38: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘->’ token
 auto makeTemplatedClass(T enumValue) -> TemplatedClass<EnumToPrimitiveType<T>::type>
                                      ^
source_file.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
source_file.cpp:44:16: error: ‘A’ is not a member of ‘Enum’
     Enum value{Enum::A};
                ^
source_file.cpp:45:34: error: missing template arguments before ‘(’ token
     auto tmp = makeTemplatedClass(value);
                                  ^
```

Answer (score 5):

Problems I see:

1. You cannot use `template<Enum T> auto makeTemplatedClass(T enumValue)` since `T` is not a type. You need to use just `template<Enum T> auto makeTemplatedClass()` and invoke the function differently.
2. You need to use `TemplatedClass<typename EnumToPrimitiveType<T>::type>` instead of just `TemplatedClass<EnumToPrimitiveType<T>::type>`. That is necessary since `type` is a dependent type.
3. You cannot use `value` as a template parameter unless it is a `const` or `constexpr`.

The following program compiles and builds on my desktop.

```
#include <iostream>

enum class Enum {
    Int,
    Long
};

template<Enum T>
struct EnumToPrimitiveType;

template<>
struct EnumToPrimitiveType<Enum::Int> {
    using type = int;
};

template<>
struct EnumToPrimitiveType<Enum::Long> {
    using type = long;
};

template<typename T>
class TemplatedClass
{
public:
    TemplatedClass(T init): init{init} {}
    void printSize() { std::cout << sizeof(init) << std::endl; }
private:
    T init;
};

template<Enum T>
auto makeTemplatedClass() -> TemplatedClass<typename EnumToPrimitiveType<T>::type>
{
    TemplatedClass<typename EnumToPrimitiveType<T>::type> ret(5);
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    Enum const value{Enum::Int};
    auto tmp = makeTemplatedClass<value>();
    tmp.printSize();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your fixes make it work indeed, but are not really a solution because of 3. unfortunately; an essential requirement is that `value` is not `const`/`constexpr`. My hope was that with `template<Enum T> auto makeTemplatedClass(T enumValue)` it would be possible to invoke this function without specifying `value` as a template parameter so that it would be automatically inferred, but as it seems this won't work.

Comment: @misev, now that you know you cannot use `value` as a template parameter unless it is `const` or `constexpr`, you should go back to the drawing board and try to come up with a solution that can work with value that can only be known at run time. I am not able suggest anything at this time since it is not clear to me what you are really trying to do.